# ZF3 error when cron runs

Tags: zend-framework, cron, zend-framework3

I've got route:

```
'console' => [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'cronroute' => [
                'options' => [
                    'route' => 'action',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\ConsoleController::class,
                        'action' => 'action',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ],
],
```

and when I run it in console:

```
php /Applications/www/project/public/index.php action
```

everything is ok, no errors

But when I try to add this script to crontab:

```
* * * * * php /Applications/www/project/public/index.php action >> /Applications/www/log/script_output.log 2>&1
```

I get errors in the log:

```
Parse error: parse error in /Applications/www/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php on line 856
```

I don't use phpunit anywhere in my code.

Answer (score 0):

My webserver uses php 7.0, command also 7.0, but cron 5.6.
Latest version of PhpUnit required >5.6, that why I get error.